# Service not being launched in onReceive AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android

Here is my onReceive inside of my AppWidgetProvider for my widget.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Log.e("stackWidgetProvider", "Inside onReceive!");

    intent = new Intent(context, widget_release_service.class);
    context.startService(intent);


}
```

The only problem is that the service is never launched.

Here is it declared in the manifest..

```
 <service android:name=".widget_release_service"
      android:enabled="true"
       />
```

Why isnt the service being launched?

EDIT:

```
@Override
```

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){

```
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Log.e("StackWidgetProvider", "Inside onUpdate");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, widget_release_service.class);
    context.startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `onUpdate` instead in the AppWidgetProvider instead of `onReceive`.

Comment: I'm stumped-- I have a project with almost identical code, and the service is being launched without difficulty! So, you are seeing those "Inside onUpdate" log messages in the console, correct?